# DataTriger Style Setter for Image Element

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, margin, datatrigger

I have an image element that is populated via databinding - if the binding returns a path, the image is drawn. If not (path comes in an an empty string), we get no image.

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=.Screenshot, Mode=OneWay}" Stretch="Fill"  Margin="5,5,5,5" />
```

That works well, except that the margin is applied to the layout no matter what (which looks bad for empty images). I figured I'd do a DataTrigger instead that only applies the margin is the path is not empty, but:

- Image doesn't seem to have a Style *(actually it does, ignore this part)*
- I don't know how to test for "string is not empty".

What I'd like to do is something like the pseudo-XAML below. Is that possible in XAML?

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=.Screenshot, Mode=OneWay}" Stretch="Fill" >
<Image.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Image">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=.Screenshot}" Value="!NullOrEmpty">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,5,5,5" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Image.Style>
```

Should I be maybe using an entirely different approach for this?

Comment: Why that strange binding path syntax with a leading period, where `Path=Screenshot` would work?

Comment: Just residue. Code is from a CustomControl, used in a ListBox

Comment: *"Image doesn't seem to have a Style"* -- it seems to for me. What are you seeing to the contrary? Is this definitely WPF?

Comment: See comment below, it was user error. Editing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it the other way round, by having a DataTrigger for the values `null` and `""`:

```
<Style TargetType="Image">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,5,5,5" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Screenshot}" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Screenshot}" Value="">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

You may probably also just have a Trigger on the Images's `Source` property:

```
<Style TargetType="Image">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,5,5,5" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Source" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks. That should help with the string detection. Need to know how to actually style the image, as well, tho - since Image doesn't actually have a .Style (see above).

Comment: Taking a 2nd look, that part was my user error. I still had the trailing slash closing my image immediately (corrected by CoolBlue in an edit above), which led to a "not present or not accessible" compile error.